# modify array after promise.all in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, foreach, async-await

I have an array like this

```
 let result =  [{id:1,name:'test',dealValue:'ds',dealType:2},{id:2,name:'test1',dealValue:'ds',dealType:4}];
```

I am looping the above array to call another function which is also a promise after each iteration I need to add the value as a new item in the current array.

```
let temp = [];

result.forEach((element, index) => {
    //build the promise    
    temp.push(getAmount(element.dealValue, element.dealType));
  });
  //execute array of promise
  let r = await Promise.all(temp);
  //add new key value pair
  result.forEach((element, index) => {
    element.IDGfee = r[index];
  });
```

This works fine, however, I am running two `foreach` loops to achieve my desired result ,is there any better way to do this??

Comment: Array items are a little bit different than the original apart from that everything is  used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.map` instead, and assign back to `element` inside a `.then` chained onto the `getAmount` call:

```
await Promise.all(
  result.map((element) => (
    getAmount(element.dealValue, element.dealType)
      .then((result) => {
         element.IDGfee = result;
      })
  ))
);
```

(Though, as comment notes, this will not wait for every response to come back before assigning to each `element` - your current code will throw before assigning if any request throws an error, whereas this may well throw after some properties have been assigned to.)

Comment: The behaviour in your code and the OP code might be different depending upon what the OP wants to do incase any one call fails.